# axios call return same value after props value changed

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

My code looks like this

child component.vue

```
<script>

export default {
props: ['Pconvs_id'],
data(){
    return{
        user : '',
        messages:[],
        newMessage : '',
        convs_id: '',
        
    }
},
created(){
    this.convs_id = this.Pconvs_id;
    this.fetchMessages();
    
},
methods:
{
    fetchMessages()
    {
        console.log(this.convs_id);
        axios.get('messages',{cons_id: this.convs_id}).then(response=> {
            this.messages = response.data;
        });
        axios.get('authuser').then(response=>{
            this.user = response.data;
        });
    },
    
    
},
watch: {
// whenever convs_id changes, this function will run
Pconvs_id: function (newConvs_id, oldConvs_id) {
  this.convs_id = newConvs_id;
  this.fetchMessages();
}},}
</script>
```

parent component.vue

```
<Message :Pconvs_id="convs_id"/>
```

my problem is that even when the convs_id changed fetchmessage() return same data what did i do wrong

axios call handler

```
public function fetchmessages(Request $cons_id)
{
    
    return Message::where([
       ['cons_id' , $cons_id],
    ])->with('user')->get();
   
}
```

Elequent relationship
message model beongsTo user and User hasMany message

Comment: I'm not certain if you syntax for where require the second element to be the operator. Does it work if you use an normal where statement? where('cons_id', $cons_id)

Answer (score 1):

I think your backend handler receives an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`
so to get the `cons_ids` you should to something like

```
public function fetchmessages(Request $request)
{
    // Get the cons_id from the request object
    $cons_id = $request->get('cons_id'); 

    // Cleaned up your "where" query
    return Message::where('cons_id', $cons_id)->with('user')->get(); 
}
```